# Software Center doesn't show files installed

Tags: software-center

When I install a program in the Software Center that happens to install a menu option, it is discoverable through the menu, but if it is a package that is documentation, or command-line only, there is no simple way to discover how to actually access the content / software.

Is there a way in the Software Center to see what files or executables were installed with a particular package so I can actually use / read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in the Software Center. If you install the Synaptic Package Manager then you can see which files were installed by right clicking the package, select Properties then choose the Installed Files tab.

The Synaptic Package Manger is available in the Software Center.

Comment: Sadness. I can't understand how the Software Center is supposed to be user friendly, if the user has literally no way to find out how to use the software installed.

Comment: You can also use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find what files/commands are provided by a package, or what package provides a particular command. For command-line programs (and some graphical programs), you can read the manual pages (by running `man COMMAND` in the Terminal, or at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/).